# Hello . I transferred Monroe currency to the wallet from Hutbit Exchange ... but it has not been deposited yet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I transferred Monroe currency to the wallet from Hutbit Exchange ... but it has not been deposited yet . I decrypted the transaction report and the confirmation was done. How can I fix the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please check the guide I have attached.